# Is it guaranteed that one thread can see the write of some shared variable from another thread finally?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

As the code listed below, in C/C++, if thread_A and thread_B run on the different CPU cores and the write/read  operation of variable "stop" both hit the L1 cache, assume that the L1 cache is very large and write-back cache strategy is used, does it mean that thread B may never stop because the new value of "stop" may never be wrote back to L3 cache or main memory?

```
bool stop = false; // global variable shared between thread A and B
// Thread A
void thread_A(){
  sleep(10);
  stop = true;
}
// Thread B
void thread_B(){
  while(!stop) {
  // .. do something
  }
}
```

Comment: No.  It isn't guaranteed.  (Thread B could load the value of `stop` from memory, put it in a *register* and then never read  it from memory again.)

Comment: Given the currently-posted code, it doesn't matter if `stop` gets written or not as the compiler is free to elide the looped access to `stop` in `thread_B`...

Comment: No, you need to use *locks, atomics* or *memory barriers*. This is often due to *cache-coherence protocols* and *weak consistency*. If `stop` is not *volatile*, it can be put in a register by optimizing compilers.

Comment: In C or  C++, *any* code like this, that writes a shared variable from one thread and reads it from another, is a data race and has undefined behavior.  Whether the new value is eventually seen is the least of your worries.  The variable typically has to either be `atomic` or else protected by a lock.  Once you do that, then you can ask about whether the new value will be seen, and the answer will typically be "yes".

Comment: I'm guessing this is meant to be C or C++ from the syntax, but please add a language tag.  Issues like this are dependent on the precise rules of the language in question and don't have completely generic answers.

Comment: @JérômeRichard If I use lock to wrap the access of "stop", is it guaranteed that thread B will see the new value of "stop"?

Comment: It depends on what programming language you are talking about. And what "lock" you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm talking about C/C++

Comment: @konchy: C and C++ are different languages. Do not tag both except when asking about interactions or differences between the languages. Pick one tag and delete the other. If you need to ask about both languages, ask in a separate question.

Comment: @konchy Just a note: in case you want to use atomics/mutexes/whatever to make `stop`'s access thread-safe, you may also want to optimize your loop (`while (!stop) {...}`), because it will likely become a very inefficient busy-loop. You may have a look at *condition variables* (like `pthread_cond_t` and `cnd_t`, depending on which library you choose) in order to optimize the loop.

Comment: Besides, you probably don`t want a busy loop like that but a cond var

Comment: It is not about caches, it is about the code compiler generates - it is allowed to assume no multithreading is involved until specific primitives invoked and e.g. completely removes the "infinite" loop in the following scenario: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/brfET9n5e (when compiled with optimizations enabled)